# When did the Virtue interlude in Quantum Thief happen?

Tags: quantum-thief

While reading the book, I came up with a very rough timeline of how things went down before the main story started. The only thing screwing that timeline up is the Virtue interlude. But let me first write my interpretation of the timeline (keep in mind this will contain spoilers for *Quantum Thief*):

First of all: I will assume Le Roi and Le Flambeur are both copies of the same mind. I don't know if either one is the original, but I don't think it matters for this question.

> Le Roi got caught early on and put into the prison on Mars.
>
> There, after a while, the prisoners took over the prison, led by a
>   group of people that I'm going to call the cryptarchs, although I
>   suspect it's a bit more complicated than that.
>
> Anyway...
>
> Since none of them could actually leave Mars, the cryptarchs decided
>   to make people forget that they were in a prison. Easier said than
>   done, until the zoku came to Mars.
>
> With the zokus' technology, they could create false memories and make
>   everyone think the Oubliette was a free city and none of them were
>   prisoners. In time, Le Roi got rid of the other cryptarchs and become
>   the one and only King of Mars.
>
> But then Le Flambeur showed up and Le Roi got jealous. After all, they
>   were both practically the same person, but Le Flambeur got to leave,
>   and go and do everything Le Roi could only dream of doing. Le Flambeur
>   really made Le Roi angry when he decided to throw it all away and
>   instead settle on Mars with Raymonde.
>
> Le Flambeur then went on to screw things up with Raymonde by cheating
>   on her. They got back together, but Le Flambeur somehow got his hands
>   on that magic box. He realized he had to hide it and would have to
>   leave Mars and his memories behind. Which he did.
>
> After he left, Le Roi decided he wanted what Le Flambeur had -
>   starting with Raymonde. Le Roi got her pregnant but then grew tired of
>   her and left her (with her still thinking it was Le Flambeur).

What really confused me though, was the Virtue interlude. In the Virtue interlude, one of Le Flambeurs and Raymondes friends (I believe it's the one he cheated with), gets told by Raymonde that Le Flambeur left. At this point, he has already lost his memories (actually... he might have just been acting now that I think about it, but I don't think it matters). He was still working on creating the place to store the box.

This all leads me to believe that this was Le Flambeur and not Le Roi. 
However, this messes with my timeline, because in this chapter, their friend mentions that Raymonde is with child, which would mean Le Roi has already spent some time with her.

I admit that my interpretation of everything might be wrong, and so my timeline would be screwed up, but I would like to know where I messed up or how the Virtue interlude makes sense without me messing up.